# How to unmarshall YAML v3 with full access to node

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to learn to use YAML v3 unmarshaling with full access to the Node in a complex embedded struct.

[The announcement](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2019/04/05/api-v3-of-the-yaml-package-for-go-is-available) post explains how to use yaml.Node, but doesn't give a serious example. And the [documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#example-Unmarshal--Embedded) also doesn't show working with the Node. The primary purpose seems to be the excellent preservation of comments in YAML files.

For example, working with an extension of the announcement article, I have

```golang
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Person struct {
        Name    string
        Address yaml.Node
    }

    data := `
name: John Doe
address: 
    street: 123 E 3rd St # street is like an avenue
    city: Denver  # A city might be a town as well
    state: CO  # A state might be a province or administrative unit
    zip: 81526 # zip might be "postal_code"
`

    var person Person
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &person)
    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshall: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled person=%v", person)

}
```

But if I try to use the address items, I find them each listed as an array of Content inside the node; there's no actual useful information there. The comments are in there, but it's not clear what they're associated with.

[Modify existing yaml file and add new data and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674853/modify-existing-yaml-file-and-add-new-data-and-comments) also deals with the same territory, but doesn't show navigating the structure after unmarshalling into the struct.

How can I navigate the "Address" node once unmarshalled, and preserve the comments on marshalling again?

Answer (score 3):

So the Node struct has three fields which are:

```
// HeadComment holds any comments in the lines preceding the node and
// not separated by an empty line.
HeadComment string

// LineComment holds any comments at the end of the line where the node is in.
LineComment string

// FootComment holds any comments following the node and before empty lines.
FootComment string
```

This ^ is taken from the documentation [here](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Node.Decode). With slight augmentation on the example above:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

func main() {
    type Person struct {
        Name    yaml.Node
        Address yaml.Node
    }

    data := `
name: John Doe
#comment here
address: 
    street: 123 E 3rd St
    city: Denver
    state: CO
    zip: 81526
`

    var person Person
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &person)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshall: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    address := &yaml.Node{}

    decErr := person.Address.Decode(address)
    if decErr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to decode: %v", decErr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", address.HeadComment)
}
```

In our case

```
#comment here
address: 
    street: 123 E 3rd St
    city: Denver
    state: CO
    zip: 81526
```

can be referred to as Node and its comments can be accessed from the fields in the Node struct. But still I am unable to get the comment above the Node, though I am able to access the other fields as pointed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the complete **struct** instead of using **yaml.Node**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Address struct {
        Street string
        City   string
        State  string
        Zip    string
    }
    type Person struct {
        Name    string
        Address Address
    }



data := `
    name: John Doe
    address: 
        street: 123 E 3rd St
        city: Denver
        state: CO
        zip: 81526
    `

    var person Person
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &person)
    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshall: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled person=%v", person)
}
```

yaml.Node seems like an **intermediate representation.**
It has to be decoded to get the values.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Address struct {
        Street string
        City   string
        State  string
        Zip    string
    }
type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Address yaml.Node
}

data := `
name: John Doe
address: 
    street: 123 E 3rd St
    city: Denver
    state: CO
    zip: 81526
`

var person Person
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &person)
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshall: %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
address := &Address{}
_ = person.Address.Decode(address)
fmt.Printf("Marshalled person=%v\n %v", person, *address)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Decode(). I'm still not understanding proper use of Node though, since per [the announcement post](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2019/04/05/api-v3-of-the-yaml-package-for-go-is-available) the biggest benefit is to be able to preserve comments and keep them in the right place. I don't understand how to do that successfully if you can't tie the contents of Node together. I updated the question to focus on access to the comments.